# Combine R objects in global environment into a list

Tags: r, list, environment

I have created a series of list objects in my global environment that I can search for by string. For example `ls(pattern = '^data_')`

How can I combine this group of named lists into 1 list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the output, we can use `mget` to return a `list` of the values from the string object/objects

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^data_'))
```